# Linq Find Item by Primary Key and display Name(that lives in a different table)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am displaying a record from my database. The record pulls data from other tables and uses a Int in the main table to represent the value so Item table has a Division equal to 1 and the Division table 1 = ALL . Now that i am displaying the records i am trying to turn the 1 into all. All the ID fields show the int. Which is what my code is telling it to do. But i am trying to display the name and when i do that i get a lot of red. It cannot find the name. `CatagoryID` should be `CategoryName`.

Hope that makes sense.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     string v = Request.QueryString["ContactID"];
     int itemid;
     int.TryParse(v, out itemid);
     var customerInfo =  GetCustomerInfo(itemid);
     CONTACTID.Text = customerInfo[0].ContactID.ToString();
     ContactTitle.Text = customerInfo[0].ContactTitlesID.ToString();
     ContactNameB.Text = customerInfo[0].ContactName;
     DropDownAddCategory.Text = customerInfo[0].CategoryID.ToString();
     DDLAddDivision.Text = customerInfo[0].DivisionID.ToString();
     ContactPhoneBox.Text = customerInfo[0].ContactOPhone;
     ContactCellBox.Text = customerInfo[0].ContactCell;
     ContactEmailBox.Text = customerInfo[0].ContactEmail;
     CextB.Text = customerInfo[0].Ext;
}

private List<Solutions.Models.Contact> GetCustomerInfo(int itemid)
{
     using (ItemContext context = new ItemContext())
     {
         return (from c in context.Contacts 
                 where c.ContactID == itemid
                 select c).ToList();
     }
}
```

This is the model

```
public class Contact
{
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int ContactID { get; set; }    
        public System.DateTime ContactCreated { get; set; }    
        public string ContactName { get; set; }    
        public int? ContactTitlesID { get; set; }    
        public string ContactOPhone { get; set; }    
        public bool cApproved { get; set; }    
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string ContactCell { get; set; }    
        public string ContactEmail { get; set; }    
        public int? DivisionID { get; set; }    
        public int? CategoryID { get; set; }    
        [StringLength(5)]
        public string CExt { get; set; }           
        public virtual Division Division { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual ContactTitle ContactTitle { get; set; }    
        public string Ext { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to flesh this out a bit. 'get a lot of red' doesn't help us to answer your questions. Also, trying to display name... where?

Comment: It isnt grabbing data from the Other table in order to pull the CategoryName that i am looking for.  It only shows the value of the current table.  In this case the `context.Contacts` is the only data that is able to been shown.

Comment: what does your mapping look like? i assume you're using linq to sql?

Comment: @alexjamesbrown I added the model.

Comment: you added the model, but not the mapping....

Comment: @alexjamesbrown Little confused on what you mean by mapping. I used Code First EF to make the models.

Comment: there's a key piece of information you were missing from your question....... I have tagged your question appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Entity Framework you can [include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) related entities in query results:

```
 return (from c in context.Contacts.Include("Catagory") 
         where c.ContactID == itemid
         select c).ToList();
```

This will return contacts with Catagory objects: `customerInfo.Catagory.CategoryName`

*BTW* instead of returning list of contacts and selecting first one by index (thus possibly having index out of range exception), modify your method to return first contact (or default, if not found):

```
private Solutions.Models.Contact GetCustomerInfo(int itemid)
{
     return (from c in context.Contacts.Include("Catagory") 
             where c.ContactID == itemid
             select c).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And use it this way:

```
var customerInfo =  GetCustomerInfo(itemid);
if (customerInfo != null)
{        
    CONTACTID.Text = customerInfo.ContactID.ToString();
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework?  Check your model again and make sure the relationship between the two tables are setup correctly.  The relationship may be missing from the model, and causing this problem.